# Magento 2 Stores Store Information unable to change Website

Tags: magento2, multistore, store-view, stores, multi-website

I have multiple stores and websites it seems the ability to change the web site is no longer available somehow. What would cause this option to be grayed out?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Goto to table "store_group" from phpmyadmin or any mysql client you are using.

Edit that table now udpate the website_id manually after that open the admin and edit that store you can now see website has been changed save the store again. This will gray down the website dropdown again.

Hope this helps!

Comment: What I am trying to do is not rename the web site the store belongs to, but switch the store to another existing web site. I was able to switch them before, but it seems the ability to do this has been grayed out.

Comment: ah ok. you can edit it from database because magento doesn't allow to change the website of existing store. I have modified my answer. please check.

Comment: If its working for you then upvote please.

Comment: I've upvoted but my reputation is lower then 15, so it's not seen to the public.

Comment: Ok no issue. When you reach to 15 then try again. Thanks